# Springdoc - Swagger UI having an array of objects with Multipart in form-data

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am having trouble setting up the swagger UI for a specific endpoint. I am having a form-data that has to fill up an array of Objects that may include MultipartFile. Till now I can represent as form-data only a single object of this type but when I request a List of these objects, swagger automatically converts it to application/json.

For example,

```
public class DocumentRequest implements Serializable {
private String documentNumber;
private Long documentType;
private MultipartFile attachedFile;
}
```

When i have this on my controller all seems good

```
@Parameter(description = "body", required = true) @Valid @ModelAttribute DocumentRequest  adapter
```

Works:

[image: works]

but when i have a List of these items it doesn't work as expected

```
@Parameter(description = "body", required = true) @Valid @ModelAttribute List<DocumentRequest> adapter
```

Does not work:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Comment: @jarvo69 unfortunately no...